# I want to draw vertical line like in twitter

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am building a twitter clone, I want to draw a vertical line like the one shown in this twitter [link](https://twitter.com/pewdiepie/status/1116366432961486848) centered between two images and happened to be in two separate `<div>`

I have tried:
`<div class="vertical-line"></div>` after the image `<div>`

```
.vertical-line {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-color: #1da1f2;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

and the result was like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cSFY.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried?

Either way, it seems like it's more of a JavaScript solution than CSS. The CSS is just for setting values - but you'll need JS to determine the distance between each given element/comment

Comment: I difficult part for me to make it vertical and under the image

Comment: plz edit your question and add what you have tried so we can help you

Comment: It looks like they have a border on the `::after` pseudo-element of the post body with some offsets.

Comment: I edited the question, any help?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create a vertical line using *only* CSS is by using `border-left` in an empty `div` with a specified `height`. As tkore mentioned in the comments, you will need to use JS to determine the `height` of the `.line` class depending on the distance between the images since you won't have this value predetermined, but the rest of this code will work as is.

```css
img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
}

.line {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 2px;
    left: 38px;
    border-left: 6px solid red;
    height: 85px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1113436678050316289/t-Agpngx_bigger.jpg">
<div class="line"></div>
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1113436678050316289/t-Agpngx_bigger.jpg">
```

You could also use pseudoelement selectors to create a vertical line, but without seeing your exact code, it would be difficult to give you a specific answer using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I just write a basic listing code and they are totally dependent on content. If content increase left bar also increase. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li:last-child .line {
  display: none;
}

.avatarWrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 28px;
}

.avatarWrap .circle {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  display: block;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}

.avatarWrap .line {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;  
  margin-left: 11px;
  width: 5px;
}

.content {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 8px 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="avatarWrap">
      <span class="circle"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="avatarWrap">
      <span class="circle"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="avatarWrap">
      <span class="circle"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form,
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="avatarWrap">
      <span class="circle"></span>
      <span class="line"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form,
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you please add margin between the circle and the text? I am having hard time to do that

Comment: @AbdulrahmanKhaled i just update `content` margin in above code snippet. I saw your codepen Good job Keep it up....

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a negative margin with positive padding. That way, you push your top element down to the child one, so it draws the line then the padding puts it back in place. No need for javascript or any messing around.

```css
.tweet {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 40px
}
.avatar {
  width: 40px;
}
.vertical-line {
  margin-bottom: -60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  background: linear-gradient(#ff0000, #ff0000) no-repeat center/2px 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tweet " style="background-color: pink">

  <div class="avatar vertical-line">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/40">
  </div>

</div>

<div class="tweet" style="background-color=yellow">

  <div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/40">
  </div>

</div>
```